# Possible integer overflow in python

Tags: python, integer, overflow

I was completing hackerrank's project euler problem #1.
I wrote a brute force solution to check my answer. It seems to be correct, except at the input of 10^9.
I have been told that the correct answer is:

233333333166666668

I am returning:

233333333166666680

```
n = 1000000000
sum_of_multiples_3 = int((int((n-1)/3.0)+1) * (int((n-1)/3.0)/2.0) * 3)
sum_of_multiples_5 = int((int((n-1)/5.0)+1) * (int((n-1)/5.0)/2.0) * 5)
sum_of_multiples_15 = int((int((n-1)/15.0)+1) * (int((n-1)/15.0)/2.0) * 15)
print(sum_of_multiples_3 + sum_of_multiples_5 - sum_of_multiples_15)
```

Comment: There is no integer overflow in Python. You *can* have floating point rounding errors..

Comment: I'm getting: 2333333316666668 ...

Comment: I am getting 2333333316666668 too

Comment: My mistake. I was missing a zero from my n. Try running it again.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are using float division where integer division will do:

```
int((n-1)/3.0)
```

is better expressed as

```
(n-1)//3
```

e.g. use Python's floor division operator, don't use a float, then floor.

Using integer floor division won't run into rounding issues as you stretch floating point arithmetic beyond its limits.

You can see this rounding error happen when you push `n` large enough:

```
>>> n = 100000000
>>> int((int((n-1)/15.0)+1) * (int((n-1)/15.0)/2.0) * 15)
333333316666665
>>> ((n-1)//15+1) * ((n-1)//15//2) * 15
333333316666665
>>> n = 1000000000
>>> int((int((n-1)/15.0)+1) * (int((n-1)/15.0)/2.0) * 15)
33333333166666664
>>> ((n-1)//15+1) * ((n-1)//15//2) * 15
33333333166666665
```

The extra 1 there comes purely from the fact that you ran into the limits of floats:

```
>>> (int((n-1)/15.0)+1) * (int((n-1)/15.0)/2.0)
2222222211111111.0
>>> ((n-1)//15+1) * ((n-1)//15//2)
2222222211111111
>>> (int((n-1)/15.0)+1) * (int((n-1)/15.0)/2.0) * 15
3.3333333166666664e+16
```

I'm not sure why you keep subtracting one from `n`; that's not needed at all and leads to incorrect results. Perhaps you were trying to compensate for float rounding errors? The correct formulas are:

```
(((n // 3) + 1) * (n // 3)) // 2 * 3
(((n // 5) + 1) * (n // 5)) // 2 * 5
(((n // 15) + 1) * (n // 15)) // 2 * 15
```

giving me the correct output for any `n`:

```
>>> n = 1000000000
>>> sum_of_multiples_3 = (((n // 3) + 1) * (n // 3)) // 2 * 3
>>> sum_of_multiples_5 = (((n // 5) + 1) * (n // 5)) // 2 * 5
>>> sum_of_multiples_15 = (((n // 15) + 1) * (n // 15)) // 2 * 15
>>> sum_of_multiples_3 + sum_of_multiples_5 - sum_of_multiples_15
233333334166666668
```

I'd have used a function here to calculate multiples:

```
def sum_of_multiples(n, k):
    k_in_n = n // k
    return ((k_in_n + 1) * k_in_n) // 2 * k
```

so you can verify that it works by comparing to a brute-force sum:

```
>>> sum(range(0, 10000 + 1, 3)) == sum_of_multiples(10000, 3)
True
>>> sum(range(0, 10000 + 1, 5)) == sum_of_multiples(10000, 5)
True
>>> sum(range(0, 10000 + 1, 15)) == sum_of_multiples(10000, 15)
True
```

then use that to calculate the answer:

```
>>> sum_of_multiples(n, 3) + sum_of_multiples(n, 5) - sum_of_multiples(n, 15)
233333334166666668
```

Comment: I get a different result with n = 200 when I do:


`(((n-1)//5)+1) * (((n-1)//5)/2.0) * 5`


and when I do:


`(((n-1)//5)+1) * (((n-1)//5)//2) * 5`

Comment: @zetologos: don't subtract 1 from `n`, and don't divide by a floating point value. You want to *floor* the division, so use `// 2`

Comment: That looks correct. But I need the result to be exclusive rather than inclusive. Example: `print(sum([i for i in range(5, 200, 5)]))`

Comment: No, the Euler problem has `n` *included*.

Comment: Perhaps, but the hackerrank version of it is exclusive. What change would have to be required to make it exclusive?

Comment: @zetologos: you'd pass in `n - 1` to the function?

Comment: @zetologos: I presume you are talking about [this challenge](https://www.hackerrank.com/contests/projecteuler/challenges/euler001); if you use `n - 1` you'll see that all test cases given pass.

Comment: @zetologos: I submitted my version:  [Python 2](https://www.hackerrank.com/contests/projecteuler/challenges/euler001/submissions/code/2762042) and [Python 3](https://www.hackerrank.com/contests/projecteuler/challenges/euler001/submissions/code/2762043). Yes, the source is the same for both; not sure if the source is public however.